# Is it necessary to do meditation on God?

Tags: gods, meditation

Okay. So I've been doing meditation. It has lots of techniques, I do it from a meditation app. Is it necessary that we do meditation in concentration of god? 
I just take the name of the lord and remember god before starting it, rest of the time it's guided by the app. Is it alright?

Comment: Question is not clear. Are you asking about app, or about meditation, or about meditating upon a particular God ?

Comment: depends greatly on what you‘re trying to achieve, maybe you could clarify

Comment: meditation is highly individualized. your guru is the only one who can tell you what meditations are best for you.

Comment: Always remember. Whatever you think , in course of time you attain that form. If you meditate on deer, you become deer. If you meditate on stone, you become stone. If you meditate on God, you will become one with God. All others = rebirth. God = Pure endless Ananda! If you meditate on God, your mind quickly becomes calm! Its like magnet!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, meditating on God is not necessary according to Patanjali, the composer of the Yoga-Sutras:

> 39. Or by the meditation on anything that appeals to one as good.
>
> **This does not mean any wicked subject, but anything good that you like, any place that you like best, any scenery that you like best, any idea that you like best, anything that will concentrate the mind.**  ( Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda,, Vol.1).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not necessary. BG 4:29 mentions pranayama, or breathe harmony. Focusing on the breath is an option. Good luck and keep at it!

Comment: Please add the BG verse with translation and transliteration.

Comment: Downvoted as it is too short.